# jQuery не отслеживает элемент в мобильной версии

Tags: javascript, jquery, bootstrap

Есть вот такой элемент:

```js
$(document).on('click', '.dropdown_services_link', function() {

  let text = $(this).text();
  $(this).parent().parent().prev().text(text);
  $('.dropdown_button_add_services__container').show();

})

$(document).on('click', '.dropdown_button_add_services', function() {

  $(this).parent().prev().after($(this).parent().prev().clone().css({
    'marginTop': '15px'
  }));

})

$(document).on('shown.bs.dropdown', '.dropdown_services', function() {

  $(this).children().eq(0).addClass('button_services__opened');

})

$(document).on('hidden.bs.dropdown', '.dropdown_services', function() {

  $(this).children().eq(0).removeClass('button_services__opened');

});
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@4.5.3/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-TX8t27EcRE3e/ihU7zmQxVncDAy5uIKz4rEkgIXeMed4M0jlfIDPvg6uqKI2xXr2" crossorigin="anonymous">
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.5.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-DfXdz2htPH0lsSSs5nCTpuj/zy4C+OGpamoFVy38MVBnE+IbbVYUew+OrCXaRkfj" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@4.5.3/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js" integrity="sha384-ho+j7jyWK8fNQe+A12Hb8AhRq26LrZ/JpcUGGOn+Y7RsweNrtN/tE3MoK7ZeZDyx" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

<div class="order-info order-info__date">
  <div class="order-info__header">
    <span>Дополнительные услуги</span>
  </div>
  <div class="order-info__inner order-info__inner___dropdown">
    <div class="dropdown dropdown_services">
      <button class="btn dropdown-toggle button_services" type="button" id="dropdownServices" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="true">
          Выберите услугу
        </button>
      <ul class="dropdown-menu dropdown_services_menu" aria-labelledby="dropdownServices">
        <li class="dropdown_services_item">
          <a href="javascript:void(0);" class="dropdown_services_link">Колеровка</a>
        </li>
        <li class="dropdown_services_item">
          <a href="javascript:void(0);" class="dropdown_services_link">Оверлок</a>
        </li>
        <li class="dropdown_services_item">
          <a href="javascript:void(0);" class="dropdown_services_link">Установка</a>
        </li>
        <li class="dropdown_services_item">
          <a href="javascript:void(0);" class="dropdown_services_link">Демонтаж</a>
        </li>
        <li class="dropdown_services_item">
          <a href="javascript:void(0);" class="dropdown_services_link">Колеровка</a>
        </li>
        <li class="dropdown_services_item">
          <a href="javascript:void(0);" class="dropdown_services_link">Оверлок</a>
        </li>
        <li class="dropdown_services_item">
          <a href="javascript:void(0);" class="dropdown_services_link">Установка</a>
        </li>
        <li class="dropdown_services_item">
          <a href="javascript:void(0);" class="dropdown_services_link">Демонтаж</a>
        </li>
        <li class="dropdown_services_item">
          <a href="javascript:void(0);" class="dropdown_services_link">Колеровка</a>
        </li>
        <li class="dropdown_services_item">
          <a href="javascript:void(0);" class="dropdown_services_link">Оверлок</a>
        </li>
        <li class="dropdown_services_item">
          <a href="javascript:void(0);" class="dropdown_services_link">Установка</a>
        </li>
        <li class="dropdown_services_item">
          <a href="javascript:void(0);" class="dropdown_services_link">Демонтаж</a>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </div>
    <div class="dropdown_button_add_services__container">
      <div class="dropdown_button_add_services">
        <svg class="dropdown_button_add_services_svg" width="24" height="24" viewBox="0 0 24 24" fill="#0078D7" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
            <path fill-rule="evenodd" clip-rule="evenodd" d="M15 11H13V9C13 8.45 12.55 8 12 8C11.45 8 11 8.45 11 9V11H9C8.45 11 8 11.45 8 12C8 12.55 8.45 13 9 13H11V15C11 15.55 11.45 16 12 16C12.55 16 13 15.55 13 15V13H15C15.55 13 16 12.55 16 12C16 11.45 15.55 11 15 11ZM12 20C7.589 20 4 16.411 4 12C4 7.589 7.589 4 12 4C16.411 4 20 7.589 20 12C20 16.411 16.411 20 12 20ZM12 2C6.486 2 2 6.486 2 12C2 17.514 6.486 22 12 22C17.514 22 22 17.514 22 12C22 6.486 17.514 2 12 2Z" fill="#0078D7"/>
            <mask id="mask0" mask-type="alpha" maskUnits="userSpaceOnUse" x="2" y="2" width="20" height="20">
              <path fill-rule="evenodd" clip-rule="evenodd" d="M15 11H13V9C13 8.45 12.55 8 12 8C11.45 8 11 8.45 11 9V11H9C8.45 11 8 11.45 8 12C8 12.55 8.45 13 9 13H11V15C11 15.55 11.45 16 12 16C12.55 16 13 15.55 13 15V13H15C15.55 13 16 12.55 16 12C16 11.45 15.55 11 15 11ZM12 20C7.589 20 4 16.411 4 12C4 7.589 7.589 4 12 4C16.411 4 20 7.589 20 12C20 16.411 16.411 20 12 20ZM12 2C6.486 2 2 6.486 2 12C2 17.514 6.486 22 12 22C17.514 22 22 17.514 22 12C22 6.486 17.514 2 12 2Z" fill="white"/>
            </mask>
            <g mask="url(#mask0)">
            </g>
          </svg>
        <div class="dropdown_button_add_services_link">
          <a href="javascript:void(0);" class="dropdown_button_add_services_link___button">Добавить услугу</a>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Выполненный через `dropdown` от bootstrap.

Не могу понять, почему в мобильной версии не отрабатывает вот эта конструкция `$(this).parent().parent().prev().text(text);` с десктопа всё ок.

Comment: А что за браузер на телефоне? версия?

Comment: без разницы какой, даже если я в том же хроме с десктопа открою мобильную версию, и загружу страницу в таком режиме - не работает

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Разобрался в чём дело, оказывается бутстрап создаёт пустой див после кнопки внутри контейнера, заменил метод поиска элемента на `$(this).parent().parent().parent().children('.button_services').text(text);` и всё заработало